# Error creating partition

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

I am trying to create a new partition in a free slot of an hard drive using the Gnome Disk utility (on 14.04). I always get the message below:

> Error creating partition on /dev/sda: Command-line `parted --align
>   optimal --script "/dev/sda" "mkpart logical ext2 119947MiB
>   225767517695b"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: You
>   requested a partition from 126GB to 226GB. The closest location we can
>   manage is 126GB to 226GB.  (udisks-error-quark, 0)

What can be the cause of this? And can it be solved?

**Edit**: A screen capture detailing the structure of this particular hard drive, with the partition at cause selected:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried partitioning with GParted?

Comment: I am trying to create an [encrypted partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage), as far as I know GParted does not have this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to create an encrypted partition in that unallocated space following [these instructions at the Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage#Creating_a_new_encrypted_partition), this being the reason why I was using the Disk Utility. But it was returning the error above, even when instructed to create a non-ecrypted partition (ext4).

Even though GParted seems to lack this functionality it succeeded in creating a non-encrypted partition in the allocated space. After that [the Disk Utility itself](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage#Encrypting_an_existing_partition) was able to encrypt the partition. In all likelihood the Disk Utility version shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 has a bug that prevents it from creating new partitions.

The detailed steps were:

1. In **GParted** select the unallocated space and select *New*, give it a label in the menu the opens and click *Add*.
2. Click *Apply all Operations* and wait for the process to finish.
3. Open the **Disk Utility**, select the newly created partition and click *More Actions* (the little icon with cogs) and then *Format...*.
4. In the menu that opens select "Encrypted, compatible with Linux systems (LUKS + Ext4)" in the *Type* drop down; create a Passphrase and click *Format...*.